# Ativar Modo Manutenção Laravel 5.1 Sem Artisan

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Sei que existe o comando `php artisan down` para ativar o modo de manutenção, mas estou com minha aplicação hospedada e não sei como dar esse comando. Teria alguma outra forma de fazer isso? Editando algum arquivo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim é possível sem terminal, mas antes vou falar do `php artisan down`, não é porque você moveu um projeto para o servidor que o comando `artisan` irá funcionar. Geralmente só movemos o projeto ou fazemos toda instalação dentro do servidor e até mesmo o projeto de um cliente ficará em um repositório então trabalhamos na base do `composer update`.

Basicamente você terá que instalar o `composer` e o `laravel` (e artisian) no servidor de produção e baixar o projeto do seu cliente por `git` (ou outro método semelhante) e o acesso será provavelmente todo por `SSH`.

Mas isto é amplo para explicar. Sem delongas irei explicar como fazer isto sem usar o `terminal`, você pode criar duas rotas (de preferencia com autenticação) e usar o método `Artisan::call`:

```
Route::get('/admin/down', function()
{
    return Artisan::call('down');
});

Route::get('/admin/up', function()
{
    return Artisan::call('up');
});
```

Ao chamar algo como `http://site/admin/down` ele irá entrar em modo de manutenção e se usar `http://site/admin/up` ele voltará ao normal.

- Documentação: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan#calling-commands-via-code
- Referencia: [Maintenance Mode without using Artisan?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21047820/1518921)

Comment: Show, vou fazer aqui daqui a pouco então. E quanto a instalação do composer e do laravel no servidor eu vou dar uma lida sobre isso tbm.

Comment: @RaylanSoares na maioria dos servidores é inviável, geralmente fazemos isto quando usamos "servidores" como o AWS.

Comment: Ah então essas hospedagens padrão q temos por aí em servidor compartilhado nem rola né

Comment: fncionou aqui, vlw!

Comment: @RaylanSoares não realmente servidor compartilhado havará muitas limitações e mesmo que seja possivel talvez seja muito trabalhoso, o melhor é trabalhar local e enviar via `ftp`, para outros comandos use o `Artisan::call` combinado com rotas.